# $\left\lfloor(\sqrt[3]{28}-3)^{-n}\right\rfloor$ is not divisible by 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

let $n$ be a positive integer.
Prove that the following expression:

$$\left\lfloor(\sqrt[3]{28}-3)^{-n}\right\rfloor$$

is not divisible by 6.

$\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "divisible by 6" for expressions involving radicals.

Comment: the expression is in brackets. meaning that its integer part is not divisible by 6.

Comment: Find a recurrence (probably of degree 3) where the behavior is estimated by this bracket (because the other two roots go to zero).

Comment: Ok, now it is clear using the floor function (clearer to use that than brackets).

Comment: @Aref: it certainly looks like a duplicate. This does not mean that anyone thinks you've copied that question, just that it is the same question and already has answers there. It is useful to note that here, before anyone spends time writing an answer that has already been given.

Comment: I'm new here. and so i think there is no problem now.